# Installing Class::Std from CPAN fails on MacBook

Tags: perl, cpan

On my MacBook, I try to install Class::Std using the command `sudo cpan Class::Std` but when I do so, the install fails with the output I've provided just below. However, when I install Class::Std using the same command on my VPS which runs CentOS 6.5, it installs just fine.

```
#   Failed test 'POD test for blib/lib/Class/Std.pm'
#   at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/Test/Pod.pm line 186.
# blib/lib/Class/Std.pm (1512): Non-ASCII character seen before =encoding in ':key?value?'. Assuming ISO8859-1
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.
t/pod.t ................ Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests
```

What could be the issue or what are some other things I can look for that might indicate what the problem is?

Comment: 1) Don't mess with the system Perl; 2) you might want to stay away from `Class::Std` unless it's a dependency; 3) the error is really nothing serious.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you mind elaborating on why I should stay away from `Class::Std`?

Comment: Doesn't look like Class::Std is part of the core modules; http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-C.html ?

Comment: It's failing on a unit test which checks pod's. Your probably ok to force an install `cpan --force Class::Std`

Comment: Too much work for too little payoff. A number of show-stopping bugs. See also [alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Std#ALTERNATIVES). Inside-out objects were an interesting experiment, but, I am not sure if they are worth the effort. `Moo` and `Moose` present excellent paths. So does plain old Perl OO.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in the documentation. It finds a non-ASCII character but the docs didn't declare an encoding. The *t/pod.t* test checks the format of the documentation so you can ignore this error and force the installation. It's nice report the problem though.

```
 $ cpan -f Class::Std
```

As for the documentation, the fix is probably to add the proper encoding at the top of the POD (plain ol' documentation):

```
 =encoding utf8
```